# Tilemap unity, получить направление конкретного тайла

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно узнать направление конкретного тайла, чтобы понять, в какую сторону по нему можно ходить персонажем.

Я вижу это примерно вот так - делаем рейкаст, получаем коллайдер, получаем из этого коллайдера конкретный тайл, из него получаем направление. Как то примерно так

```
var k = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.2f);
var tile =  k.collider.GetComponent<Tilemap>().GetTile(new Vector3Int((int) k.point.x, (int) k.point.y, 0));
```

Но вот в чем проблема - у объекта Tile нет никакого направления. А если брать направление напрямую из коллайдера, то оно нулевое. Т.е. `transform.forward` показывает наверх, `transform.right` направо, что точно не соответствует направлению тайла - оно примерно на 45*. Прикладываю скриншот, чтобы было понятно, откуда рейкаст и что мне нужно получить.

Comment: Можешь поподробнее. Может я глупый, но я ничего не понял! Что за направление тайла? И зачем ты его используешь что бы персонаж мог по нему ходить? Ты можешь добавить коллайдер(ы) тайлом что бы персонаж мог по ним ходить!

Comment: @ArtsemGorbatchev просто мне нужно чтобы персонаж ходил не в произвольную сторону, а конкретно прямо по направлению тайла. Допустим тайл - текстура в виде стрелки, и стрелка показывает куда то. И мне нужно чтобы персонаж шёл по этой стрелке, а не просто бегал по коллайдеру.